# Can't keep cells in a div table at 50%

Tags: jquery, html, css, ecmascript-6

I wish to have two columns where if I press on an entry in one column it will get sent to the other column. However, I can't get each cell to stay at 50%. How should I solve this?

Html:

```
<div class="divsholder">
  <div id="col-1" class="column"><div id="col-1-0">l</div><div id="col-1-1">e</div><div id="col-1-2">f</div></div>
  <div id="col-2"><div id="col-2-0">r</div><div id="col-2-1">i</div><div id="col-2-2">g</div><div id="col-2-3">h</div><div id="col-2-4">t</div></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#divsholder {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/barra/121v4ow8/24/

So this is what I'm after:

```
L   R
E   I
F   G
    H
    T
```

but I'm getting this:

```
L   R
E   I
F   G
   H
T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the **Flexbox**:

```js
let a = ["l", "e", "f"];
let b = ["r", "i", "g", "h", "t"];

let f = (data, id, func) => {

  data.forEach((n, i) => $('#' + id).append(    
    $('<div/>', {
      'text': n,
      'id': id + '-' + i
    }).on({
      'click': () => func(i)
    })
  ))
}

f(a, "col-1", (i) => {});

f(b, "col-2", (i) => {});
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

.divsholder {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.divsholder > div {
  flex: 1;
}

div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="divsholder">
  <div id="col-1" class="column"></div>
  <div id="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

Set the parent `.divsholder` to `display: flex` and make all the children the same width with `flex: 1`.

Answer (score 3):

I would try something simple emulating the way Grid builds their boilerplates, as long as you always want to keep this 50% (two-columns) layout.

HTML - add the column class to both divs so they can behave the same way

```
<div class="divsholder">
  <div id="col-1" class="column"></div>
  <div id="col-2" class="column"></div>
</div>
```

CSS - Adjust your width and margins for gutter

```
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
}
```

See the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/121v4ow8/43/). Sometimes easy does it!